# jQuery set Multi Select OptGroup options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Multi-Select list with OptGroups like so:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="idCountry">
    <optgroup label="ASIA">
      <option value="AUSTRALIA">AUSTRALIA</option>
      <option value="CHINA">CHINA</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="EUROPE">
      <option value="FRANCE">FRANCE</option>
      <option value="UK">UK</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

How can I have jQuery select all the destinations in Europe only for the user by Label? How do I unselect all the destinations in an Optgroup by Label as well?

Added for Ejay's amusement. This is what I've tried but it doesn't work and I don't know where to go from here.

```
$(".chkRegion").click(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        var optgroup = $('select optgroup[label="' + this.checked + '"]')
        optgroup.attr('selected', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: write some code to accomplish the task and post here if you get stuck at some point.

Comment: @JimC The request above isn't for amusement; its a relative requirement; if you want people to invest their time and energy into helping you, the least you can do is volunteer what you've already tried; it helps in a few ways.  For one, we know you've put effort into solving your problem.  For two, we know what you've tried and why it isn't working, and can better direct you to a solution.  For three, we know what not to give you.

Comment: Ok, I'll be more mindful of this next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set

```
$('optgroup[label=EUROPE] option').prop('selected',true);
```

Change label value and boolean accordingly to unselect

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y48bgdfe/1)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
var element = $('optgroup[label=EUROPE] option');
element.prop('selected', 'selected');
```

In case you have multiple select with same group label, add id of select in selector

```
var element = $('#idCountry optgroup[label=EUROPE] option');
element.prop('selected', 'selected');
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k1bzpe2g/)